# uploaded images don't change without refresh

Tags: php, image, caching, laravel

I am building a CMS that allows changing out some image banners on the homepage. The trouble I am running into is that the images are cached (by the browser?) and won't show up until the page is refreshed. This is true for the admin page (which shows the current images), as well as visiting the 'homepage' where the images are shown to normal page visitors.

I haven't timed it precisely, but this was lasting even if I opened a new tab and visited the URL. It only changes once I refresh the page.

For what it's worth, here is the code I use to update the images:

```
    $asset = 'homepage_'.Input::get('asset').'.jpg';
    File::delete(public_path().'/img/'.$asset);

    $file = Input::file('upload');
    $file->move(public_path() .'/img/', $asset);
```

Is there a way I can tell the server to 'reload' that image so that when it is changed the admin doesn't need to refresh the page?

Answer (score 1):

if it is cache problem ;

add parameter to URLs

`http://localhost/uploads/myimage.jpg?id=11644477200`

in your code ;

`echo $image . "?id=". time();`

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the image on upload might help, depending on what's actually cached. You probably want to modify the filename in some way anyway.

If you're allready doing this, take a look at the response headers and see if you can change something there.

Answer (score -1):

EDITED: found a proper solution.

You want to add a variable to your image url which would be the last modified time as int. You do that like this:

```
define("SITE_URL","http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/");
define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

$fmt = filemtime ( SITE_ROOT ."/img/imagename.jpg" ); 
echo "<img class='whatever' src='". SITE_URL ."img/imagename.jpg?".$fmt."' />";
```

Comment: Clearing the `stat()` function cache has nothing to do with browser caches.

Comment: You were right. I found a proper solution now though with image.jpg?filemtime(image.jpg) when fetching for showing in <img />